# Can I enter the UK with my EU spouse, marriage certificate, and my German Blue Card?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, eu, spouses

I am a non-EU citizen and working in Germany with Blue Card residence permit. I got married to an EU citizen after I came here.

We want to travel to the UK but, as I read it, the UK lets you enter if you have an Article 10 residence card.

Is it possible for me to travel to UK with my spouse and with our marriage certificate?

Comment: You might be able to get in that way by train or ferry, but not by air.  It's safer to get an EEA family permit; the process is relatively painless unless you have a long way to travel for the application. There should already be some questions about this here, and there may be some at [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Are you asking about using these documents in addition to a passport, or instead of a passport?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that. I could pass the police check but couldn't pass easyjet. I believe I have right to enter but easyjet has some strict rules. Do not try that if you are planning to by air.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain what your problem will be: It may be that the UK would let you enter. Your problem is that you have to get there somehow, which will be by air, Eurostar, or ferry. And they check your papers. And they will say: It may be that the UK would let you enter.

Bet we are not SURE that the UK will let you enter, and if they don't, then it gets very expensive for the operator, who will have to take you back to where you come from, and may get fined for letting you on board.

So when your papers are checked, by a company that doesn't take any risks, you will most likely be rejected. Not because you are not allowed to enter, but because they don't want to take any costly risk.

Comment: yep that happened as I explained :)

Comment: With the eurostar and most ferries, the passport control takes place before boarding.  I also think that the rules surrounding sea passengers are not as strong as they are for air travelers.  That is why the problem arises only for air travelers.

Answer (score 0):

The Border controls are the same for air, sea and train. As above an EEA Family Member permit is the way to go and it'll give you  safe legal way to travel.

Comment: It's legal for a traveler who normally requires a visa to enter the UK as an EEA family member without an EEA family permit, but airlines won't board EEA-family passengers with visa-required passports unless they have one (or an article 10 card).  That is why there is a distinction between the different modes of transportation.